# Error during QLDB ledger export through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

I'm trying to export QLDB data through AWS CLI by following that documentation:

- https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/qldb/export-journal-to-s3.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/export-journal.request.html

Command executed:
 `aws qldb export-journal-to-s3 --name my-ledger --inclusive-start-time 2022-11-06T00:00:00Z --exclusive-end-time 2022-11-07T23:59:59Z --role-arn arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/service-role/AmazonQLDB-ServiceRole-11111111--s3-export-configuration s3://testBucket`

Getting the following error:
**Error parsing parameter '--s3-export-configuration': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input: s3://testBucket**

I want to understand the bucket format accepted by the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the example from the link you mentioned.

You can create a json file `my-s3-export-config.json` with this content:

```
 {
     "Bucket": "awsExampleBucket",
     "Prefix": "ledgerexport1/",
     "EncryptionConfiguration": {
         "ObjectEncryptionType": "SSE_S3"
     }
 }
```

And use that file as an input of your cli:

```
aws qldb export-journal-to-s3 \
    --name myExampleLedger \
    --inclusive-start-time 2019-09-18T00:00:00Z \
    --exclusive-end-time 2019-09-18T22:59:59Z \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-s3-export-role \
    --s3-export-configuration file://my-s3-export-config.json
```

Comment: Thank you @anthony-b, it worked fine once I declare the json with bucket settings first.